# Xamarin Android: How to increase max jdk memory for layout renderer in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I'm developing a rather complex user interface in Xamarin Android for Visual Studio 2012.  There are four versions of this interface, Normal, Small, Large and Landscape.  When I added the Landscape layout (the last one), the JDK that runs the renderer run up to 890 Mb usage and I assume is thrashing the garbage collector as it's using 50% of the CPU on a quad-core system.  Sometimes the layouts will load, but more often I get a blank white box in the middle of the layout and have to shut down both visual studio and kill the jvm that's run amok.

Is there a way to tell the SDK to use 2G of memory instead of 1G for the renderer?

Comment: In project properties you have Android Options. In Advanced tab you can set Java Max Heap Size. Hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you can now go to:

Project Properties > Android Options > Advanced (tab) > Java Max Heap Size

2g will give you 2GB